# return to full backstack when app started (a) from android market (b) then home

Tags: android, android-intent

Steps:

1. User starts app from Android Market application
2. User clicks "Start child"

   stack: ActivityMain > ActivityChild
3. User presses home button and returns to the app through "launch icon"
4. Android opens "last task" + create next ActivityMain

   stack: ActivityMain > ActivityChild > ActivityMain

I expect that click on "lauch icon" will just return to previous stack [without actually creating new activity].
I expect stack:

```
ActivityMain > ActivityChild
```

How to achive it???

On the other hand, when user in the above 1st step starts app dicertly from "launch icon" then the problem does'n exist.

Manifest:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="ActivityMain"
        android:name=".ActivityMain" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="ActivityChild"
        android:name=".ActivityChild" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Introduce "launcher activity" which is responsibe for:
- either starting new task,
- or restoring previous task.

Launcher is started as "singleInstance".

```
public class ActLauncher extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityChild1.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
}
```

For example, assume we have activities:

```
ActLauncher [mode=singleInstance]  
ActChild1 [mode=standard]  
ActChild2 [mode=standard]
```

Now at some moment user executed sequence:

```
AndroidMarket > ActLauncher > ActChild1 > ActChild2
```

then HOME
and then return to app but by launcher icon "ActLauncher".
This brings user to full previous back stack:

```
ActChild1 > ActChild2
```

I applied the solution in [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=your.life.helper)
There:
- ActLauncher = "invisible"
- ActChild1 = main screen
- ActChild2 = game screen

Best wishes!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to read up on the `android:launchMode` and `android:clearTaskOnLaunch` attributes of `<activity>`: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Comment: I read it a few times - even more, I read a few times all activity params :) I tried launchMode="singleTask" as it seems to be the closest to required behaviour. But there is a problem with "singleTask" - when you call ActivityMain (with "singleTask") then it will also clean back stack (remove ActivityChild).

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood what you wanted. I've updated the answer.